# CI 3.1.0 error of non-loading of form_validation library

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.0
while loading my form_validation library it gives me error
**Message: Undefined property: Email::$form_validaiton**
I have loaded the helper class of **Form** I have also tried loading **form_validaton** library in autoload and also loading it explicitly in the **Constructor** but the problem is not solved.
Give me suggestions to resolve this problem.

```
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validaiton->set_rules('name', 'Name', trim|required);
        $this->form_validaiton->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', trim|required|valid_email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mispelled it.

```
$this->form_validaiton->...
```

Should be

```
$this->form_validation->...
```

It should all work fine now.

Comment: oh I got it, Thank you so much !